Cannot access class 'org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset'
I'm trying to use kotlin-spark-api library in my project to use Spark for few dataframe operations. Rest of all components are in kotlin. Now, I am trying this:
withSpark() {
    val eventsDf = spark.createDataFrame(extractedEvents, EventDict::class.java)
    val sortedDf = extractedEventsDf.sort(col(EventColumns.DATETIME).asc())
    val windowSpec = Window.orderBy(EventColumns.DATETIME)
    transformedEvents = sortedDf.withColumn(EventsDfColumns.LOOKUP_ID, row_number().over(windowSpec))
}

Added these to my gradle:
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx.spark:kotlin-spark-api_3.3.2_2.13:1.2.4")
compileOnly("org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.13:3.3.2")

Now, I'm seeing one error in this:
Cannot access class 'org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

Can someone please help on how can I fix this? Thank you.

This is an issue with Java compatibility. I was using Java 21 and Spark 3.3.2 doesnt support Java 21. I switched back to Java 17 and this issue is resolved now.
